# Dynamic For Next Loops

Tags: vb.net

Currently working on this code that needs the iteration to reach 13, and the index has been incorrect. I receive no error in the code, but I can not seem to figure out how to figure out why the index is wrong.

Initial: 3 Terminating: 28 Step: 2

The current output reached is Iteration of 1 - 9 (need 13) and the index is 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, and 26

My output Received:

[image: Output Received]

Here's the output Desired:

[image: Desired Output]

```
Public Class frmLab23
    Private Sub btnDisplayValues_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplayValues.Click
        Dim initialValue As Integer
        Dim terminatingVal As Integer
        Dim stepVal As Integer
        Dim iterationCount As Integer
        initialValue = CInt(txtInitial.Text)
        terminatingVal = CInt(txtTerminating.Text)
        stepVal = CInt(txtStep.Text)

        'Iteration
        For index As Integer = stepVal To terminatingVal

            If stepVal < terminatingVal Then
                'Increase counter
                iterationCount += 1

                'Insert to list
                lstValuesOfIndex.Items.Add("Iteration: " & iterationCount & "   Index: " & stepVal)

                'current index 
                stepVal = initialValue + stepVal
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] for us. The only concrete value you've given is `13`, but we have no idea of the starting point of your code so how can we know what is wrong with it? We need complete instructions on the input state and the final output state you're expecting and what is the current incorrect output.

Comment: *"I can not seem to figure out how to figure out why the index is wrong"*. By debugging your code. Set a breakpoint at the top and then step through the code line by line. before each step, determine exactly what you expect to happen and compare that to what did happen afterwards. As soon as reality doesn't match expectations, you've found an issue. Even if you can't resolve it, at least you can provide use with all the relevant information.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have all of the right variables, but you've put them in odd places.

Try this code:

```
Dim initialValue As Integer = 3
Dim terminatingVal As Integer = 28
Dim stepVal As Integer = 2
Dim iterationCount As Integer = 0
For index As Integer = initialValue To terminatingVal Step stepVal 
    iterationCount += 1
    Console.WriteLine("Iteration: " & iterationCount & "   Index: " & index)
Next
```

That gives me:

```
Iteration: 1   Index: 3
Iteration: 2   Index: 5
Iteration: 3   Index: 7
Iteration: 4   Index: 9
Iteration: 5   Index: 11
Iteration: 6   Index: 13
Iteration: 7   Index: 15
Iteration: 8   Index: 17
Iteration: 9   Index: 19
Iteration: 10   Index: 21
Iteration: 11   Index: 23
Iteration: 12   Index: 25
Iteration: 13   Index: 27
```